# Getting Updated Value In Another Struct - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

My @ObservedObject doesn't seem to be updating when the value changes, I've tried reading the articles already and I guess it's reading the original Object, rather than the updated one. The 2nd file isn't a view, I just want to get the value to then run any arbitrary functions on them.

File 1:

```
    import SwiftUI

class UserSettings:ObservableObject {
    @Published var username = "initial value"
    
    func checkValues(){
        print(self.username)
    }
}


struct SettingsView: View {
    
    @StateObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    var myotherThing = OtherThing()
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack{
                Text("Username")
                    .padding()
                TextField("Enter username...", text: $userSettings.username, prompt: Text("Required"))
                    .padding()
                Button("check current value", action: userSettings.checkValues)
                    .padding()
            }
            VStack{
                Text(userSettings.username)
                    .padding()
                Button("call other function", action: myotherThing.printerFunction)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class OtherThing {
    
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    func printerFunction(){
        print("hello world...")
        print("username entered", userSettings.username)

    }

}
```

Comment: You can't use an `@ObservedObject` outside of a SwiftUI `View`. It inherits `DynamicProperty` and it needs a `body` to get updated values.

Comment: Thank you, how would I pass this value then to another Swift class that isn't a view? Am I able to just pass them as parameters to the function?

Comment: You can pass the object as normal, you just can't observe them with a SwiftUI wrapper `.sink` may be an option if needed.